# how to take list as input and feed it to function

Tags: python-2.7

```
import sys
a=sys.stdin.read(1)
l=list(a)
print l

def genSubset(l):
    res=[]
    if len(l)==0:
        return [[]]
    smaller=genSubset(l[:-1])
    extra=l[-1]
    new=[]
    for small in smaller:
        new.append(small+extra)
    return smaller+ new
print genSubset(l)
```

this is my code now how can i take input as list ,and feed it to the function .every time it  displays error that cannot concatenate str to list,so want to know how input a list.i have tried it with input()and raw_input(), and then using list function but still the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this modifications:

```
l = input("INPUT: ")
#print type(l) # list
#print l

def genSubset(l):
    res=[]
    if len(l)==0:
        return [[]]
    smaller=genSubset(l[:-1])
    extra=l[-1]
    new=[]
    for small in smaller:
        #print type(small) # list
        #print type(extra) # int
        new.append(small + [extra])
    return smaller+ new
print genSubset(l)
```

**Example**

```
>>>
INPUT: [1, 2, 3]
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code `extra` is string.

```
>>> l = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> extra = l[-1]
>>> extra
'3'
```

To get a list with the last item, use slice notation:

```
>>> extra = l[-1:]
>>> extra
['3']
```

---

```
def genSubset(l):
    res=[]
    if len(l)==0:
        return [[]]
    smaller=genSubset(l[:-1])
    extra=l[-1:] # <---
    new=[]
    for small in smaller:
        new.append(small+extra)
    return smaller+ new

>>> genSubset(['1', '2'])
[[], ['1'], ['2'], ['1', '2']]
```

BTW, using `sys.stdin.read(1)`, you always get a string of length 1 (or 0).

Comment: i used sys.stdin.read() ,that kept prompting endlessly for input,so searched stackoverflow and in one question i saw read(1),so i thought it prompts only once ,so can you please correct me

Comment: @SaranshGupta, How about using `raw_input()`. It will read a line and return that line (without trailing newline).

Comment: but i want to use sys.stdin coz raw_input cannot be used for input large data

Comment: @SaranshGupta, Why do you think `raw_input` cannot be used for large data?

Comment: in codechef problems forum they recommend people to use sys.stdin input for some specific problems tha involve large data like ENORMOUS INPUT TEST problem

Comment: @SaranshGupta, Alternatively you can use `sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()`, but that will not make any difference.

Comment: plz explain why you used rstrip()

Comment: @SaranshGupta, used `rstrip()` to remove trailing newline character (`\n`).